# How to fetch "created_at" date while applying a coupon code in cart page

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, coupon, coupon-codes

This is regarding mass generation of coupons. I generate many coupons under single rule.

When I apply anyone of those coupons in the cart page I need to perform custom validation apart from magento default validation.

I need to fetch the 'created_at' date displayed in mass generate coupons backend grid.

Can someone tell me how to fetch this parameter.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: I have no clue from where to fetch it. I tried various possibilities but unable to arrive at the solution. I am able to fetch parent rule name and rule id alone from the following event. **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost**. Actually the parameter is set in **Mage/SalesRule/Model/Coupon/Massgenerator.php** inside generatePool action.

Comment: $modelcollection = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection();
              $newCollection =array();
              $newCollection = $modelcollection->getData();
  
              $ruleName = $newCollection[0]['name'];
              $rule_id=   $newCollection[0]['rule_id'];

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule'); 
$rule->load($couponCode);
```

where $couponCode is the id of the rule and then fetch everything you need with `$rule->getData()` or `$rule->getCreatedAt()`.